# Change column width depending on the selectedvalue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap and have the following structure somewhere in my code:

```
.row
  .col-md-6
    content1
  .col-md-3
    content2
  .col-md-1#id_selector
    content3
  .col-md-2
    content4
```

I also have a js script that shows/hides the column with `#id_selector` depending on a select value from one of the select fields.

What I want to achive is to change the 
`.col-md-3` to `col-md-4` when `.col-md-1#id_selector` is hidden
and set it back to 3 when it's shown

How can I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need javascript for this:

```
document.getElementById('myButton').onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById('column-to-change').className.replace('col-md-3', 'col-md-4');
}
```

Note: With no code provided in the OP, I'm simply providing the basic outline using `onclick`. If you can post some code, it will be easier to troubleshoot.